# Alert Dialog pops up 27 times in handler

Tags: android, handler, countdowntimer

My alert dialog keep pops up for 27 times. I have implement handler and inside the handler, i use the CountDownTimer. Alert dialog code is on CountDownTimer's onFinish. Below are my codes.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {





    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.face_detect_surface_view);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (Tutorial3View) findViewById(R.id.tutorial3_activity_java_surface_view);

    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);



    mPath=getFilesDir()+"/facerecogOCV/";

    labelsFile= new labels(mPath);

    Iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    textresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage( Message msg) {
            Log.e("X", (String) msg.obj);

            if (msg.obj=="IMG")
            {
             Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
             canvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
             Iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
             if (countImages>=MAXIMG-1)
             {
                 toggleButtonGrabar.setChecked(false);
                 grabarOnclick();
             }
            }
            else
            {
                textresult.setText(msg.obj.toString());

                textpercent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textpercent.setText( mLikely + "%");


                new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        final AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(FdActivity.this).create();
                        ad.setTitle("Recognition Status");
                        ad.setMessage("Criminal ID :" + textresult.getText().toString() + "\nSimilarities : " + textpercent.getText().toString()  );
                        ad.setButton("Rescan", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Rescanning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Bundle configBundle = new Bundle();
                                onCreate(configBundle);
                                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();



                            }
                        });




                        ad.show();//pops out 27 times

                        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
                        buttonSearch.setChecked(false);


                    }
                }.start();

            }

        }
    };
    text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    buttonCatalog=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonCat);
    toggleButtonGrabar=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonGrabar);
    buttonSearch=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonBuscar);
    toggleButtonTrain=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    textState= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewState);    
    textpercent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewpercent);
    imCamera=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
   textpercent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
        text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        textresult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    
        toggleButtonGrabar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);      
        text.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((text.getText().toString().length()>0)&&(toggleButtonTrain.isChecked()))
                    toggleButtonGrabar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    toggleButtonGrabar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            return false;
        }
    });

    toggleButtonTrain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (toggleButtonTrain.isChecked()) {
                textState.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.SEnter));
                buttonSearch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                textresult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textresult.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.SFaceName));
                if (text.getText().toString().length() > 0)
                    toggleButtonGrabar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textpercent.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            } else {
                textState.setText(R.string.Straininig);
                textresult.setText("");
                text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                buttonSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ;
                textresult.setText("");
                {
                    toggleButtonGrabar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.Straininig), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fr.train();
                textState.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.BLANK));

            }
        }

    });
    toggleButtonGrabar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            grabarOnclick();
        }
    });

    imCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mChooseCamera==frontCam)
            {
                mChooseCamera=backCam;
                mOpenCvCameraView.setCamBack();
            }
            else
            {
                mChooseCamera=frontCam;
                mOpenCvCameraView.setCamFront();

            }
        }
    });

     buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (buttonSearch.isChecked())
                {
                    if (!fr.canPredict())
                        {
                        buttonSearch.setChecked(false);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.SCanntoPredic), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                        }
                    textState.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.SSearching));
                    toggleButtonGrabar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    toggleButtonTrain.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    faceState=SEARCHING;
                    textresult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    faceState=IDLE;
                    textState.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.SIdle));
                    toggleButtonGrabar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    toggleButtonTrain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    textresult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
            }
        });

    boolean success=(new File(mPath)).mkdirs();
    if (!success)
    {
        Log.e("Error", "Error creating directory");
    }
}
```

Somebody please help me to fix this problem. I am still a learner in Android Programming. I did not have idea on how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe mHandler call `public void handleMessage(Message msg)` 27 times?

Comment: no, check you other code. mHandler where used and called?

Comment: inside the public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { }

Comment: please show, I want to see how you use your mHandler

Comment: I have updated the question with full code

Comment: Check out my answer, use Log to gather information why it is called 27 times, then go from there.

Comment: Good, but is not what I want. I want see something like this code: mHandler.sendEmptyMessage();

Answer (score 0):

I think your handler gets passed that amount of messages. You could verify that with a

```
Log.e("X", msg.obj);
```

and check the logcat for that output.

Comment: Where do i paste this?

Comment: Right before this line `textresult.setText(msg.obj.toString());`

Comment: 11-04 00:49:31.789    9487-9487/com.example.arafat.portablefacerecognitionsystem E/X﹕ h
11-04 00:49:31.794   9487-10308/com.example.arafat.portablefacerecognitionsystem D/CameraBridge﹕ mStretch value: 1.0416666
11-04 00:49:31.807    9487-9487/com.example.arafat.portablefacerecognitionsystem D/JavaCameraView﹕ Preview Frame received. Frame size: 622080

Comment: I am getting this on logcat for 27 times